# AngularJS route like SammyJS, Grapnel or Satnav?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes

How can I create a route in AngularJS like SammyJS?

Example:

```
.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/photos/:date', {
            controller: function($scope) {
               // foo
            });

});
```

I don't need a template or ng-view, I need to execute a ajax request and open a modal, for example.

Any idea? Tks guys

Answer (score 0):

```
.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/photos/:date', {
            templateUrl: 'someView.html', 
            controller: function($scope,$http) {

               $http.get('/someUlr').then(function(res){});
            });

});
```

Try this